# Web scraping from "http://" sites gives 403 error

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to scrape the `HTML` body from certain websites using `cURL`. This is my code:

**PHP**:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');

    $final = array();
    if(isset($_POST["url"])){
        $urls= json_decode(stripslashes($_POST["url"]),true);
        foreach($urls as $url){
            $user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) 
            AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36"; 
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
            $html=curl_exec($ch);
        }
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo "Data not found";
        }
        else{
            if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 200){
                @$DOM = new DOMDocument;
                @$DOM->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html);
                array_push($final,$DOM->getElementsByTagName('h1')[0]->textContent;); 
            }
        }
    }
    if(count($final) > 0)
        echo json_encode($final);
?>
```

**JS**:

```
function webscrape(urls) {
    let jsonstring = JSON.stringify(urls);
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/fetch_url_data.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{"url":jsonstring},
        cache:false,
        timeout:60000
    });
}

let urls = ["https://........","http://............"];
let fetched_data = [];
(async()=>{
    let response = await webscrape(urls);
    if(response[0] == '['){
        const arr = JSON.parse(response);
        for(var x in arr){
            fetched_data.push(x);
        }
    }
}();
```

---

I've found that when I give URLs starting with `http://` as input, then I get a 403 error from server. But when I use `https://` URLs as input, the data is fetched succesfully. Why is that?

Comment: sites dont maintain both http and https that would be foolish. So if they are https and you try and address them as http, you either get forwarded or blocked Suggest you read what a 403 error is [http error 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)

Answer (score 0):

Error 403 is the "Forbidden" error - simply said, the server you are scraping from rejects your request. Many of todays websites will not accept HTTP connections as they are a security risk for the user.